# How can you make a Discord's bot commands not case sensitive?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I have a Discord bot running discord.py which replies Hello! to anyone saying Hello while the bot is running. The code looks like

```
if message.content == "Hello":
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
```

It works, but only if the message is in the exact same case as the original message. I would like it so that if someone said hello, then it would also return Hello! Is this possible, or do I just have to encode every single case of the Hello string?

Comment: I suggest you look into casefold() with string.
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/casefold#:~:text=The%20casefold()%20method%20removes,method%20does%20nothing%20to%20it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply convert the message content to lowercase, then compare it against lowercase commands. This way no matter how the input was capitalized the bot sees the same result of "hello".

```
if message.content.lower() == "hello":
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
```

Comment: Does this work in a prefix, where the prefix is a symbol like 

if message.content.lower() == prefix + "hello":
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

Comment: Run through some example inputs in your head and see if you can determine if they would work or not. If your prefix is "a?" and you send a message like "A?hELLo" what will be compared on the left and right side?

Comment: How would this work for a .message.content.startswith?

Comment: @RyanYin message.content.lower() returns a string, you can just call startswith on that

Comment: What code would that look like if it was the hello function?

Comment: @RyanYin please ask a new question instead of continuing to add additional ones in the comments here

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make case-insensitive commands using command decorators, when instantiating the bot you can do:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", case_insensitive=True)
```

But when you're using the `on_message` event, you can convert it to lower-case:

```py
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower() == "hello": # make sure the comparison string is all lower-case
        await message.channel.send("Hello!")
```

---

**References:**

- [`Bot.case_insensitive`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.case_insensitive)